# Python is not connecting with SQL

Tags: mysql-python

For the code
[please check the code what's wrong with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsaIl.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsaIl.jpg)

For the above code there is error
[please help to solve this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIfZD.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsaIl.jpg)

Comment: The heck is `imimport`?

Comment: I checked it but again it showing a error

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Do you have a database set up already? Is it to a local database or an external database? Do you have an existing user that's allowed to connect from the ip you're trying to connect from?

Comment: I have local database

Comment: I don't know about the existing users

Comment: Make sure your credentials work and the database is up. You can try this in a DBA like MySQL Workbench. Generally there's a user like root:root, root:pass, or root without a password whatsoever that is setup when you install mysql. If not, generally there's a maintenance user that has a password stored in visible text somewhere within a mysql config file. I know where this file is on linux but not on windows unfortunately.

Comment: You can also try connecting from your CLI with a command like `mysql -u myusername -p` then type your password.